# Vim Regex: Two regexes conflicting

Tags: regex, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

In trying to write a syntax file for an in-house language, I'm trying to capture the *first* word of every line preceded by a `/` and assign it to one `hi def link`, and the *second* word of every line (enclosed by `/` and `/`) and assign it to a second `hi def link`.

For the syntax:

```
cmo/create/mo1///tri
createpts/brick/xyz/2,2,2/0.,0.,0./1.,1.,1./1,1,1
```

I am trying to capture `cmo` and `createpts` as `argOne`, and `create` and `brick` as `argTwo`:

```
syn match argOne '^\zs[^\/]\+\ze\/'
syn match argTwo '^[^\/]\+\/\zs[^\/]\+\ze\/'

hi def link argOne         Type
hi def link argTwo         Statement
```

The issue is that they conflict: when both `sys match` statements are present, ViM only captures those found by `argOne`. But in isolation, when one of the two `syn match` is commented out, either `argOne` or `argTwo` will work perfectly.

How can I get these two statements to play nice with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create contained matches, define an `argOneTwo` which matches the first two arguments, and then provide matches for the first and the second match:

```
syn match argOne '^\zs[^\/]\+\ze' contained
syn match argTwo '\/\zs[^\/]\+\ze\/' contained
syn match argOneTwo '^\zs[^\/]\+\/[^\/]\+\ze\/' contains=argOne,argTwo

hi def link argTwo         Statement
hi def link argOne         Type
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nextgroup=...` to build a sequence of syntax groups that are matched. This scales better than @herbert's solution of defining a parent group that contains individual syntax groups.

```
syntax match argOne "^[^/\\]\+" nextgroup=sepOne
syntax match sepOne "/" contained nextgroup=argTwo
syntax match argTwo "[^/\\]\+" contained
```

Note that `sepOne` and `argTwo` have the `contained` attribute, so that they are only matched when instructed via `nextgroup=...`. Without that, they would match in much more locations.